# How to disable Angular animations using dynamic providers?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to disable all Angular Material animations on my page at runtime based on user preferences (button click). I know that I can do it by importing `NoopAnimationsModule`, but I can't do it dynamically (after user interaction in application).

I'm using Angular Material 8.2 - generally my idea was to import `BrowserAnimationsModule` normally in my `AppModule`, but to change providers. At first I did it manually:

```
{ provide: AnimationDriver, useClass: NoopAnimationDriver },
{ provide: ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE, useValue: 'NoopAnimations' }
```

It worked, so then I wanted to take advantage of 'useFactory' to do it more dynamically:

```
{ provide: ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE, useValue: 'NoopAnimations' },
{ provide: AnimationDriver,
  deps: [SomeService],
  useFactory: (someService) => someService.getDriver()
}
```

---

```
import { ɵNoopAnimationDriver as NoopAnimationDriver } from '@angular/animations/browser';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeService {
  animationsDisabled: boolean = true;

  constructor() {
  }

  getDriver(): any {
    if (this.animationsDisabled) {
      return new NoopAnimationDriver();
    }
  }
}
```

It worked, but when I wanted to return `AnimationDriver` (from `BrowserAnimationsModule`) based on function `instantiateSupportedAnimationDriver()` implementation from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.ts) there was a problem.
Both `new WebAnimationsDriver()` and `new CssKeyframesDriver()` set manually are working, but only in some part. Can't really say why - 70% animations work as expected, 30% not.

```
import { ɵNoopAnimationDriver as NoopAnimationDriver } from '@angular/animations/browser';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeService {
  animationsDisabled: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
  }

  getDriver(): any {
    if (this.animationsDisabled) {
      return new NoopAnimationDriver();
    } else {
      return new WebAnimationsDriver();
      // or return new CssKeyframesDriver()}
  }
}
```

Next problem/question is - does changing field `animationsDisabled` dynamically (using for example `Subject`) can reload `useFactory` and change `AnimationDriver`? Maybe there is some other way to do it?

My another try was to use `*` selector in CSS and set all transitions, transform and other animation properties, but it breaks some other stuff like placeholders:

[image]

Is there any way to accomplish this dynamically at runtime?